# How to upload blob to Azure from reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, azure, blob

In my application i have recorded video and able to capture blob of that. Now i just want to upload the blob to Azure using ReactJs application. Could someone help me out with the solution with required steps and process.
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Sravan Kumar Shetty

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far and the issues you’re running into.

Comment: Pls see [here](https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html)

Comment: Thanks@Jayendran For reply. I have tried to use the same, for that i have downloaded the library and added to my application. But showing error for "createBlobServiceWithSas" not found. More over i want to send blob instead of file to Azure could you please help me out.

Comment: It will be better to show code snippets with what you have tried so far so that people can understand the issue better and even reproduce the issue. Otherwise it is really hard to us to know what is wrong. 
Sometimes even a snippet is not enough, then you should consider providing a sample project with the problem.

Comment: Thanks Everyone with your solutions. I have converted blob to file and uploaded that file to Azure Finally